# Why the error 'The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null' when using Include

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have the following POCO entity in a code first Entity Framework 6.1.3 application:

```
public class JobTitle
  {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int JobTitleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual int? PostId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
  }
```

The entity configuration is as follows:

```
  public class JobTitleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<JobTitle>
  {
    public JobTitleConfiguration()
    {
      Property(j => j.PostId).HasColumnName("Post_PostId");
      HasOptional(j => j.Post);
    }
  }
```

The following query gives the null value error, if there are JobTitles without an associated Post:

```
var list=JobTitles.Include(j=>j.Post).ToList();
```

I do not understand why, because the foreign key is nullable and specified as optional in the configuration.

How can I eager load the Post information, but still avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Is your PostId property inside the Post class also nullable?
- Are there any null values for "JobTitleId" on your database?

Comment: PostId is the primary key of Posts, and database generated - so it cannot be nullable. Again JobTitleId is a primary and database generated, so no null values.

Comment: I see... Are there any other "Int" types on the "Post" class?

Comment: Thank you this was helpful, but did not completely solved my problem:

Comment: The Post class has a property of type Scale, which is marked as optional in the entity configuration. The Scale class in turn has a composite key made up of two integers. If I eliminate the Scale property, the error goes away. If make the composite key ints nullable, I get a null reference exception in the hash key lookup. Strangely if I make sure that all Post instances have populated Scale properties I still get the error. So I need to dig some more or post a new question.